# c++ initializing struct with struct pointer

Tags: c++, struct

While I was reading C++Primer, I came across this code

```
struct destination;
struct connection;
connection connect(destination*);
```

What does `connection connect(destination*);` line do? and how come it compiles fine even though it's passing the struct name? Aren't you supposed to initialize the `struct` to variable then pass that like so?

```
struct destination;
struct connection;
destination dest;
connection connect(dest);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does `connection connect(destination*);` line do?

It declares a function called `connect`, that takes a `destination*` and returns `connection`.

In this declaration, a name is not provided for the parameter (which, though not particularly helpful to the reader, is valid). Presumably, that'll be provided when the function is *defined*, like so:

```
connection connect(destination* ptr)
{
   connection conn;
   // do something with conn and ptr
   return conn;
};
```

The rest of the book's code snippet (the part that you did not quote) shows a call to the function `connect`, from within another function called `f`.

Function declarations were covered six chapters prior.

> how come it compiles fine even though it's passing the struct name?

Because that's what you're supposed to do in a function declaration.

> Aren't you supposed to initialize the `struct` to variable then pass that like so?

No.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I was confused if it was making a connection struct called connect or it was a function returning a connection

Comment: @qwertyz: The only way to really tell is exactly how you (almost!) did: where the type `destination*` is, this can only be a declaration. It wouldn't be valid to call a function (or, to initialise an object) like that.